# truffle doesnt migrate to new chain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I was following some tutorial and everything worked fine. I decided to make a new project to test myself out. After writing the contracts and making a new ganache workspace, when I run `truffle migrate`, it just says:

```
Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang
```

It doesnt say anything regarding the migrations.

When I run `truffle networks`, it says: `Contracts have not been deployed to any network.`

Also, when I run `truffle develop`, when it lists down the accounts, its showing the old accounts from my older ganache workspace.

truffle-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ganache: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  mocha: {
    useColors: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: How exactly are you running ganache-cli?. What flags are you providing?

Comment: tried using `truffle migrate`, `truffle migrate --reset`, and `truffle migrate --reset --network ganache`.

Comment: No. I mean how are you running ganache?

Comment: I just start the ganache application

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly connected to the provided network?. and is ABI getting generated when you compile?

Comment: Yes, the ABIs are being generated. If I run `truffle develop` it lists the address connected to the network so I can assume I am connected to a network, just not the right one

Comment: You can make it certain by providing a network id in your truffle-config.js. and run this command in terminal to start ganache: ```ganache-cli -p 7545 --networkId [id here]```

Comment: nope. still not working. used with matching host, port, network Id. However, I did try and ran my previous project and the tests still works. Does it not work when you have 2 seperate projects?

Comment: I dont think that would be a problem considering you have done the configurations right for both.

Comment: So no answer yet? I'm having the same problem...